# What is the simplest way to play music from the web in a voice channel

Tags: discord.py

What is the simplest non-hackish way to play music from the web to a voice channel in Discord.py 1.7.3? I'm using `client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")` although I'm not sure if I have Discord.py voice support installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The discord.py library provides an MIT-licensed example for playing music with youtube_dl
[here](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/examples/basic_voice.py). These music commands work not only with URLs, but also with just the name of a song, artist, etc.

To install voice support, you can use:

```
# Linux/macOS
python3 -m pip install -U "discord.py[voice]"

# Windows
py -3 -m pip install -U discord.py[voice]
```

([source](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py#installing))

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at this.